# After Update errors on Memory optimized tables SqlServer

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2016, row-level-security, memory-optimized-tables

Using EF 6.1.3, SqlServer 2016. I have recently modified certain tables in my DB to memory optimized tables. Everything functions correctly, however, when I added an after update trigger on a non-memory optimized table I get the following error.

SQL Server Assertion: File: <"d:\b\s1\sources\sql\ntdbms\hekaton\engine\core\tx.cpp">, line=7434 Failed Assertion = '!(tx->ErrorObject != nullptr) || (err == nullptr || tx->TempTableTx)'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.

Note: There is a predicate on the table for row level security which does uses memory optimized tables.

Has anybody else encountered this/found a solution?

Thanks!